# Resizing UIToolbar when UISearchBar becomes active

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uisearchbar, uitoolbar

I have an `UIToolbar`with 5 items:

1. `UIBarButtonItem` with image
2. `UIBarButtonItem` flex width
3. `UIBarButtonItem` with custom view (`UISearchBar`)
4. `UIBarButtonItem` flex width
5. `UIBarButtonItem` with image

When I select the `UISearchBar`, I get it to keep its correct size and become active. However, I would like the image to the left and to the right to disappear and give the `UISearchBar` the full width of the `UIToolbar`. How do I do that?

This is what I have:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3077127/demo_1.mov

And this is what I want:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3077127/demo_2.mov

This is my code:

```
#pragma mark View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[...]

    SearchBar *mySearchBar = [[SearchBar alloc] init];
    mySearchBar.delegate = self;
    [mySearchBar sizeToFit];
    [mySearchBar setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
    [mySearchBar setTintColor:[UIHelpers getSlColor]];

    CGRect searchBarFrame = mySearchBar.frame;
    searchBarFrame.size.width = 218;
    [mySearchBar setFrame:searchBarFrame];

    UIView *searchBarContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:mySearchBar.frame];
    [searchBarContainer addSubview:mySearchBar];
    [searchBarContainer setTag:99];

    UIBarButtonItem *left = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"location-arrow"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *right = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"location-arrow"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *search = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBarContainer];

    NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:left, flex, search, flex, right, nil];

    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [toolbar setItems:items];
    [toolbar setTintColor:[UIHelpers getSlColor]];

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = toolbar;
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];

[...]

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

#pragma mark -
```

Comment: Hey, check my SO answer over here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12394703/719656), it is similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: That does seem to work. However, I don't use the interface builder, but do it all by code... which should work as well. Add your reply as an answer and I'll approve it.

Comment: Glad to be of help :) Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my answer to a similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12394703/719656)

The key to a correct animation is to specify `UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews` as an option for the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have tried this, but maybe you can use the [UISearchBarDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchBarDelegate) methods to get notified when the user clicks on the search bar.

Example:

```
    #pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate Methods

    - (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
      // Remove the right and left buttons from the ToolBar
      [self updateToolBarWithImages:NO];
    }

    - (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
      // Add back the right and left buttons to the ToolBar
      [self updateToolBarWithImages:YES];
    }


    #pragma mark - Private Methods

    // Custom method used to Update the ToolBar
    - (void)updateToolBarWithImages:(BOOL)iShowImages {
      // Logic to update ToolBar based on the BOOL value in showImages
      // use "setItems:animated:" method of UIToolBar to set the ToolBar Items
      [toolBar setItem:items animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: I have tried updating the toolbar, but if I remember correctly it didn't go smoothly. Since the tools exists of an array with items, updating the items would result into sudden update (not animated) or not happen at all.

Comment: have you tried the `- (void)setItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated;` method of UIToolBar to set the ToolBar Items ? Updated the answer accordingly. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I did, but I am currently not sure. I'll try it as soon as I get home tonight and see if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't give me the result I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a ToolBar for that.
Simply use a NavigationBar, with your 2 right and left ButtonItems, plus add to the NavigationBar's titleView a SearchBar with the appropriate delegates.

So you don't have to resize your NavigationBar. It's just about adding/removing the NavigationBar's right and left ButtonItems animated like so:

```
if (self.searchBar.isActive) {
     [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
     [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
}
else {
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:self.leftButton animated:YES];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:self.rightButton animated:YES];
}
```

Hope this helps!