# Including UISearchBar in toolbar in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I am trying to place a UISearchBar on toolbar in an .xib file.
i am able to drag and drop the search bar onto the toolbar but it shows the following error.

`ControllerName.xib:error: illegal Configuration: UISearchBar embedded in UIBarButtonItems (Only available ub iPad documents).`

Please guide me how to include the UISearchBar into the Toolbar in xib.

Comment: You'll get a possible solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309441/ios-using-uisearchdisplaycontroller-with-uisearchbar-that-is-uibarbuttonitem-i

Comment: no need to add searchbar in toolbar.... u can add it and change it's properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know unless you are using **IPAD** for your development, you can not add `UISearchBar` directly in `UIToolBar` in **IPHONE** , you need to add the UISearchBar to a customView first and then add it to the toolbar programatically

```
// your searchbar
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xposition, yposition, width, height)];

//create a customview and make its frame equal to your searchbar
UIView *searchBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:searchBar.frame];

// add your searchbar to the custom view
[searchBarView addSubview:searchBar];

//finally add it to your bar item of the toolbar

UIBarButtonItem *searchBarItem =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBarView];
```

Comment: Won't that approach get one's app rejected?

Answer (score 0):

By Programetically:

```
UIToolbar *Toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [Toolbar sizeToFit];

    UISearchBar *testbar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,2,250,38)];

    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnCancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(ButtonMethod)];
    [barItems addObject:btnCancel];

    [Toolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

    [Toolbar  addSubview:testbar];

    [self.view addSubview:Toolbar];
```

Here is Button Method;

```
-(void)ButtonMethod
{
  // Write Code for ButtonMethod Method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this Interface Builder now that Apple fixed this in **Xcode 8.2**. I think they disabled it before because popovers were not allowed on iOS before iOS 8.0 and a search bar in a toolbar implies that a popover will be used most times. But they forgot to disable it with iOS 8.0.