# Swift - UISearchBar in UIToolbar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uitoolbar

How can I create A UISearchBar inside of a Toolbar in Swift? If I use the Interface Builder I get the following error:

`error: Illegal Configuration: UISearchBar embedded in UIBarButtonItems (Only available in iPad documents)`

Is there a Swift solution for this problem? The Toolbar will only be available on iPad.

Comment: UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
UIBarButtonItem  * searchBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBar];

UIToolbar  * searchToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0+20,[self view].bounds.size.width,32)];

[searchToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchBarButtonItem,homeButtonItem, nil] animated:YES];

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065220/including-uisearchbar-in-toolbar-in-ios

Comment: Thank you for the code, but I was wondering if there is a solution in Swift.

Comment: Apple fixed that error in Xcode 8.2. The interface builder method should work on iPhone now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIToolBar is just a custom UIView, so you have three options (that I can see) for your implementation:

First, if you want to stick the search bar in the toolbar here's the code:

```
var searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50))
var myView = UIView(frame: searchBar.frame)
myView.addSubview(searchBar)
var barButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem(customView: myView)]
toolBar.setItems(barButtonItem, animated: false)
```

Second, if you want the search bar in the nav bar on your screen you can do the following:

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50)) 
navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(searchBar)
```

Third, if you need the toolbar to be elsewhere, you can create your own custom UIView that looks like a toolbar (spans the width of the screen) and add the search bar to that.  You can even make this new toolbar of yours a custom class so it's reusable throughout your program.

Cheers!